# EditText.getText().toString() returns hint. How to return empty String instead?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I've noticed that `EditText.getText().toString()` returns even the hint. Is there any way to **not** return the hint if the EditText field is empty?

Sure I can check if `toString()` returns the hint but that does not sound very reasonable.

Here is the XML of my EditText:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/add_assignment_title_edittext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/add_assignment_title_textview"
    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="@string/title_hint"/>
```

This is how I use it:

```
EditText titleEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.add_assignment_title_edittext);
// Then I access it with
String titleStr = titleEditText.getText().toString();
```

Comment: You need to do `EditText.getText.toString()`

Comment: What does your EditText contain?

Comment: It is empty. I'll post the xml

Comment: @Pants and if there's some relevant Java code, also post that.

Comment: I simply access it with EditText.getText().toString() @Sufian

Comment: @Pants weird. As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21218791/1276636) says, hint will only be returned with `editText.getHint()`. Maybe you need to rebuild/clean build the project.

Comment: @Pants please see if you are not setting the text from other location.

Comment: @Sufian Forgot t update. After a clean rebuild it worked... very strange.

Comment: @Pants now you've experienced firsthand how cool the clean build feature is in Android development. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21218791/1276636) states, hint will only be returned with `editText.getHint().toString()`.

If you are doing neither of the following then the only thing you can try is to **rebuild/clean build the project**:

1. `editText.setText()` in your Java code, nor
2. `android:text="@string/title_hint"` in your XML.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know want you want to do with `EditText.toString()`. But if you want that `toString()` return something special the best way is to create a custom EditText.

Like :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class CustomEditText extends EditText {
    public CustomEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        //return what you want
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
yourEditText.getText().toString();
```

You need the "getText()" method first.

Comment: Sorry, this is exactly what I meant. It still returns the hint if nothing else is entered.

Answer (score 0):

Use `editText.getText().toString()`

**Edit:**
Here some code, probably the error is in your xml

main_activity.xml:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Write here"/>
```

MainActivity.kt:

```
val editText = findViewById(R.id.text_view) as EditText
println("-> ${editText.text}")
```

Output without typing anything:

```
$ ->
```

Output typing 'hello':

```
$ -> hello
```

Only for completeness, MainActivity in java code:

```
EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.text_view);
Log.d(TAG,"-> "+ editText.getText());
```

Comment: I apologize but yeah this is what I meant. It still returns the hint if nothing else is entered.

Comment: @Pants I think you need to restart your IDE and clean build (if you're on intellJ or Android Studio then do restart with invalidate cache). If still it doesn't work, perhaps you need to change your device emulator. If still not then post your complete java and XML code.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
EditTextName.getEditableText()
```